# Count combination of 2 fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I would like all the plays of a song per radiostation.

```
class Airplay(Timestamps):
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    radio = models.ForeignKey(Radio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    airedAt = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
```

I try to calculate the airplay like this

```
Airplay.objects.all().annotate(play_count=Count(Concat('song__id', 'radio__id'), distinct=True)).order_by('play_count')
```

I see several occurrences of a song x station combination. But `play_count` is always 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Airplay.objects.values('song', 'radio').annotate(play_count=Count('*')).order_by('play_count')
```

This will count the number of times a `song` instance is played on a `radio` instance.